# Same list with different orderings, how to get same ordering?

Tags: c#, list

i am looking for a solution that isnt as awkward as mine.

I have two lists, both containing data about parts from a car.
My ordering of the parts is different to the one i get from an api.
What i have for now:

```
private static List<Part> parsedDents = new List<Part>();

foreach (var dent in dentDetails.Dents)
                {
                    Part buffer = new Part();
                    int p = 0;

                    buffer.alu = oldReportModel.parts[p].alu;
                    buffer.paint = oldReportModel.parts[p].paint;
                    buffer.glue = oldReportModel.parts[p].glue;
                    buffer.install = oldReportModel.parts[p].install;
                    buffer.replace = oldReportModel.parts[p].replace;
                    buffer.plastic = dent.Plastic;
                    buffer.count = dent.TotalDents;
                    buffer.size = dent.AvgDiaMm;
                    buffer.index = oldReportModel.parts[p].index;
                    p++;
                    parsedDents.Add(buffer);
                 }
return parsedDents
```

then i put it in my DB, but the order is not correct, now i could change it to part[0] = myPart[3] and so on, but i want a better way.
I know the order it comes in and can explicitly create every part and order it in the way i like but this is not a good and clean solution for me. I have the same names in the parts, so there has to be a way to map it through this !?
Thanks for any help or tips to get me finish this.

Comment: "a solution that isnt as awkward as mine" so then show your solution

Comment: Is this a guessing game where we try to figure out what your code is? If so, my money is on "trying to sort integers as strings".

Comment: Perhaps you can create a small list of few element that illustrate each case you have. [mre]

Comment: Could you please show us the code of your current solution, so we can better understand your question.

Comment: You're saying there are names but you aren't setting a name in `buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
var orderedParts = oldReportModel.parts.OrderBy( p => p.???? ).ToList();
var orderedDents = dentDetails.Dents.OrderBy( d => d.???? ).ToList();

//TODO deal with the situation when lengths don't match

for(int i; i<orderedParts.Count; i++)
{
  part = orderedParts[i];
  dent = orderedDents[i];

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i have done to make it more slim:

```
 switch (dent.Part)
                    {
                        case "Hood":
                            buffer.index = 0;
                            break;

                        case "LeftFrontFender":
                            buffer.index = 1;
                            break;

                        case "LeftFrontDoor":
                            buffer.index = 3;
                            break;
```

So i set the index manually via the part name. After this i order by index:

```
List<Part> orderedParsedDents = new List<Part>();
                orderedParsedDents = parsedDents.OrderBy(p => p.index).ToList();
```

i think this is not the best solution, but slimmer than my first one, and working.